# How to iterate over only the first few elements using *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to develop an angular(version 6) application and am using *ngFor inn a place to iterate over an array. In the HTML I only want to view the first 8 elements due to the output design becoming uneven. The rest of the elements can be stored for a next button call essentially.
I know one method of approach is limiting the array on which I'm calling *ngFor on itself to 8, but that seems like more of a hack than anything else. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
HTML----->

```
<div *ngIf="!isloading" style = "padding-right: 300px; padding-left: 300px">
    <ng-container *ngIf="cards">
    <div *ngFor ="let card of cards">
    <app-card [card]="card" ></app-card>
    </div>
</ng-container>
</div>
<div class ="loader" *ngIf = "isloading">
```

JS--->

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-feed',
  templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feed.component.css']
})
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() cat :string; 
  @Input() sucat:string;



  //These 4 to represent current feed cat and supercat
  private curcat : string;
  private cursu : string;
  private page : number;
  //to  determine if page loading 
  private isloading : boolean = false;


  //These to  deal with the the JSON of the response Data
  private cards : Card[] = [];
  private itemcount : number;
  private lastpage : number  = 10;
  constructor(private contentservice: ContentService) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes : SimpleChange){
    this.currentfeedparam(this.cat,this.sucat);
    this.fetchdata(this.cursu,this.curcat);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
  }

  currentfeedparam(c:string,s:string){
    //this fucntion to set feed status
    this.curcat = c;
    this.cursu = s;
    this.page = 1;  
  }

  fetchdata(su :string,cat : string){
  this.isloading = true;  
  if(this.lastpage >=  this.page){
    this.contentservice.getcontentdata(cat,su,this.page)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.isloading = false;  
      const data = new JsonData(response);
      this.lastpage = data.lastPage;
      console.log(this.page+' '+this.lastpage);
      this.page++;//
      this.cards = data.items;
      });

  }
  else{
    console.log('last page reached');
    this.isloading = false;  
  }
}

}
```

Comment: you could just define a function in your class, ex. `take4()` which returns the first 4 elements of your array, and then in your template write `*ngFor="let card of take4(cards)"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try this solution

You can use `slice` pipe.

```
<div *ngIf="!isloading" style = "padding-right: 300px; padding-left: 300px">
  <ng-container *ngIf="cards">
     <div *ngFor ="let card of cards | slice:0:8;">
       <app-card [card]="card" ></app-card>
     </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
<div class ="loader" *ngIf = "isloading">
```

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1:**

1. Create a new array and put the items you want to show there, e.g

   ```
   this.filteredCards = this.cards.slice(startIndex, 8);
   ```

and use it in your loop, changing the startIndex when you want to show other cards:

```
<div *ngFor ="let card of filteredCards">
    <app-card [card]="card" ></app-card>
</div>
```

**Method 2**

```
<ng-container *ngFor ="let card of cards; let i=index">
  <div *ngIf="i <= 8">
    <app-card [card]="card" ></app-card>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answers, but in method 2 it still loos over the entire collection. I think op wanted to just  short circuit the loop.